# Method for get id through value - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

Through this query I find a element in a database by value and take the id:

```
Model::where($table,'=',$value)->first()->id;
```

But I need to create a method, because I use this code with other models; a possible example:

```
public function getId($model,$table,$value) {
    ...
}
```

How can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method

```
public function getId($model, $table, $value) {
    return $model::where($table, $value)->first()->id;
}
```

### Usage

```
$id = getId('App\User', 'name', 'John Doe');
```

From your code, it looks like you have this as a class method. Instead, you could create this as a global helper so you can access it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

trait GetIdByNameTrait
{
    public function scopeGetIdByName($query, $name)
    {
        return $query->where('name', $name)->first()->id;
    }
}
```

The models should use it:

```
use Traits\GetIdByNameTrait;
```

Then you can use this everywhere;

```
$id = Model::getIdByName($value);
```